# How can I use nouveau and nvidia on my 2 GPUs?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, nouveau

As a result of a major compatibility problem on Xubuntu 16.04.3, since Ubuntu has dropped x86 support, the driver for my motherboard's `GeForce 6150SE nForce 430` GPU (which I'm trying to use for my secondary monitor) fails to build.

The nouveau driver for this chip is newer than the run file I could get my hands on for it, but I had do disable it to install the driver (run file) for my `GeForce GT430`, which is the pci-e card I'm using for my primary monitor.

What I want to do is use nouveau for my 6150SE while using the run file for my GT43O and have both monitors operate under a single X-screen with xinerama.
(the idea is to reduce load on my GT430)

How can I do this??

Also I have no means of connecting the PC to internet or I wouldn't need to use run files to begin with.
(I can download stuff with this phone and transfer it to my PC, but that's it)

Comment: well I no longer need this as nvidia helped me get both cards working off the legacy 304.137 driver, which is newer than the nouveau-provided driver... I'm not too happy with it because the 340.366 driver for my GT430 seems to have used GL version 4.5.0 while this legacy driver seems to only use 2.1.2, but I'm at least happy it works. Fingers crossed this doesn't hinder the work I used to do.

Comment: also I had to reinstall Xubuntu 16.04.3, and the x86 support issue magically fixed itself. idk what happened to break the first installation... probably the CPU clock on the odd interval instead of the even... hu hu hu